# <input /> leaves its outlines on other pages

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a input box placed in the header `data-role="header"` of a jQuery Mobile page.

```html
<form id="form-search" class="form-search" style="display: none; background-color: #fff; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;">
  <input type="search"** placeholder="Enter your search query" name="search-query" id="search-query" value="" data-mini="true" /> 
</form>
```

When this form gets submitted, page is changed `$.mobile.changePage()` but there is still an outline for that search box. How is it possible?

I tried using `blur()` on inputbox after form is submitted but it doesn't work. Also this is the only place where any inputbox leaves its trace on other page.

Comment: I'd assume the header will remain in the browser on every page. Maybe it should go in the data-role="content" section instead?